# Make a horizontal page view with sliding title

Tags: flutter

I am trying to implement a horizontal page view in Flutter. I find it easy to implement the page view but I am not able to figure out that how to change the title as in the following UI:

[image]

e.g. when the next arrow is clicked, I want to show the next page with the default animation and I also want to update the title to something like `2. Page 2` with the same animation but not move the arrows.

How may I achieve this?

Comment: can you include your best effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code example:

result:

[image: flutter page view with next previous button]

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp2());
}

class MyApp2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp2> createState() => _MyApp2State();
}

class _MyApp2State extends State<MyApp2> {
  var pageController = PageController();
  late num currentPage = pageController.initialPage;
  var titleController = PageController();
  var pageTitles = [
    "1. Login Page",
    "2. Profile Page",
    "3. Products Page",
    "4. Settings Page",
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    pageController.addListener(() {
      currentPage = pageController.page ?? 0;
      if (currentPage is int) {
        setState(() => {}); //for hiding next or previous button when we are in last or first page
      }
      titleController.position.correctPixels(pageController.offset *
          titleController.position.viewportDimension /
          pageController.position.viewportDimension);
      titleController.position.notifyListeners();
    });
  }

  void nextPage() {
    pageController
        .animateToPage(
          (pageController.page ?? 0).toInt() + 1,
          duration: kThemeAnimationDuration,
          curve: Curves.decelerate,
        )
        .then((value) => setState(() => {})); //for hiding next button when we are in last page
  }

  void previousPage() {
    pageController
        .animateToPage(
          (pageController.page ?? 0).toInt() - 1,
          duration: kThemeAnimationDuration,
          curve: Curves.decelerate,
        )
        .then((value) => setState(() => {})); //for hiding previous button when we are in first page
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      scrollBehavior: ScrollConfiguration.of(context)
          .copyWith(dragDevices: {PointerDeviceKind.mouse, PointerDeviceKind.trackpad, PointerDeviceKind.touch}),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xff221D28),
          title: Row(
            children: [
              if (currentPage == 0) //hide previous button
                const SizedBox(width: 32)
              else
                InkResponse(
                  onTap: previousPage,
                  child: const Icon(Icons.chevron_left, color: Colors.white, size: 32),
                ),
              Expanded(
                child: SizedBox(
                  height: kToolbarHeight,
                  child: IgnorePointer(
                    child: PageView.builder(
                      controller: titleController,
                      itemCount: pageTitles.length,
                      itemBuilder: (c, i) => Center(
                        child: Text(pageTitles[i], style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              if (currentPage == pageTitles.length - 1) //hide next button
                const SizedBox(width: 32)
              else
                InkResponse(
                  onTap: nextPage,
                  child: const Icon(Icons.chevron_right, color: Colors.white, size: 32),
                ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: PageView.builder(
          controller: pageController,
          itemCount: pageTitles.length,
          itemBuilder: (c, i) => Center(child: Text(pageTitles[i])),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```